# Prevent from string not to break inside <td> table tag

Tags: html, css

I have a table and text inside  tags inside, when I am adding space, the line breaks inside the  tag. How can I avoid this break?
You can see below the HTML code and link to codepen for example.

```html
<div id="new-id">
  <table bgcolor="#123456" style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif;padding:10px;position:relative;min-height:46px; width:100%; padding:0;">
    <tbody>
      <tr height="100%" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100% !important">
        <td width="16px" valign="center" align="center" style="width: 16px; max-width: 16px !important; border:0; min-height: auto !important; outline:none; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; padding:0;">
        </td>
        <td>
          <table cellspacing="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse !important; height:100% !important; min-height: 44px; width:calc(100% - 60px) !important; max-width: 100% !important; direction:ltr; padding: 0; margin: 0; margin-top:6px; margin-bottom:6px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif;"
            direction="ltr">
            <tbody style="color: #654321">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img src="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAAQAABILAAASCwAAAAAA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" alt="awareness" style="height: 18px; width: 18px; border: none; margin-top: 5px;" />
                </td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: 600;padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;text-align: start;">
                  <strong>
                                        Notice! YT
                                     </strong>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100%; padding-left: 1px; font-size: 12px;">
                  Contact Us ASAP.
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

See link to codepen here:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tommyahav/pen/YzWLBdW)

Comment: "How can I prevent text from wrapping with CSS?" is an FAQ. Have you done your research?

Comment: yes, I did but I didn't find any question that looks like my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage your td width.

See code below, I've added widths to your tds. Your code was applying 100% width to the last td making the others smaller.

```html
<div id="new-id">
  <table bgcolor="#123456" style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif;padding:10px;position:relative;min-height:46px; width:100%; padding:0;">
    <tbody>
      <tr height="100%" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100% !important">
        <td width="16px" valign="center" align="center" style="width: 16px; max-width: 16px !important; border:0; min-height: auto !important; outline:none; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; padding:0;">
        </td>
        <td>
          <table cellspacing="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse !important; height:100% !important; min-height: 44px; width:calc(100% - 60px) !important; max-width: 270px; !important; direction:ltr; padding: 0; margin: 0; margin-top:6px; margin-bottom:6px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif;"
            direction="ltr">
            <tbody style="color: #654321">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img src="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAAQAABILAAASCwAAAAAA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" alt="awareness" style="height: 18px; width: 18px; border: none; margin-top: 5px;" />
                </td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: 600;padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;text-align: start;">
                  <strong>
                                        Notice! YT
                                     </strong>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 1px; font-size: 12px;">
                  Contact Us ASAP.
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it supposed to be closer to each other and not far.

Comment: If you want equal sizing for all tds then remove width property from tds and add a fixed width to the table instead. See the updated code snippet above, you can see that I've applied a max-width of 270px to the table. You can adjust this to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like css property `white-space: nowrap` is what you are looking for.

```
<strong style="white-space: nowrap;">
          Notice! YT
</strong>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still didn't fix the problem.